# Perché "reni" si pronuncia con la "e" chiusa quando ha il significato di "lombi" e con la "e" aperta quando sono invece gli organi interni?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, accents

Mi sono appena accorta di un aspetto della lingua italiana che mi sembra davvero curioso (e molto difficile da ricordare): nell'italiano standard,
["reni"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/reni) quando ha il significato di "lombi" o "regione lombare" si deve pronunciare "réni", con la "é" chiusa. Invece, quando ["reni"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/rene)
sta per gli organi che producono l'orina deve essere pronunciato "rèni", con la "è" aperta. Questo mi sembra molto curioso perché in spagnolo esiste un'unica parola, ["riñones"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WUplJtw), per indicare questi due concetti (una cosa simile accade in catalano). Inoltre, la voce ["réni"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/reni) del Treccani indica "cfr. rène", mentre alla voce ["rène"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/rene) si legge "cfr. reni". Sapreste spiegarmi qual è la ragione di questa diversa pronuncia della vocale "e" di "reni"?

Comment: Veramente io ho sempre detto e sentito dire «réni» (con l’«é» chiusa) per entrambi i significati, ma vivo nell’Italia del Nord, dove diciamo «pésca» anche quando dovremmo dire «pèsca».  Sottolinerei piuttosto un’altra differenza: «réni» nel significato di «lombi» è femminile (come ci ricorda l’esecrabile, e infausto, «spezzeremo **le** reni alla Grecia») e può essere usato soltanto al plurale, mentre «rène», l’organo, è maschile è può essere anche singolare.  Immagino che la differenza di pronuncia scaturisca da qui.

Comment: Mai sentito con la e aperta

Comment: Pronuncia toscana, @Alex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questo articolo dall’[Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/r-due-plurali) tratta della diversa origine  dei due “reni”, da cui probabilmente la diversa pronuncia:

> **Nell'italiano standard attuale i due plurali *i rèni* e *le réni* (con e chiusa), stando alla pronuncia registrata nel DOP) rimandano a due lemmi distinti:**
>
> - il primo è del sostantivo maschile *rène*, che indica l'organo interno, dal latino *rene(m)*
> - l'altro è un sostantivo femminile usato solo al plurale che indica la 'regione lombare' o anche la 'schiena', dal latino plurale *renes* (GRADIT).
> - Bruno Migliorini, in *Lingua d'oggi e di ieri*, Roma, S. Sciascia 1973, scrive: "Il termine latineggiante *il rène* si è imposto nella lingua dei medici, e attraverso di essa nella lingua comune, respingendo nell'uso veterinario o culinario il termine di *arnioni*  e *rognoni*, e invece lasciando sopravvivere in altro senso il termine ereditario *le reni*" (p. 203). Il sostantivo maschile *rene* quindi avrebbe fatto tardivamente ingresso nella nostra lingua (alla fine del XVII sec.), quando lo sviluppo della scienza medica ha creato la necessità di una denominazione specifica per l'organo in riferimento all'uomo, distinguendolo dalla parte commestibile dell'animale macellato.

Come suggerito da DaG:

> secondo lo Zingarelli “le reni” è in uso dal 1268, mentre “il rene” come organo da un momento imprecisato prima del 1698. L'[*Enciclopedia Dantesca*](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/rene_%28Enciclopedia-Dantesca%29/) conferma che in Dante compare (una mezza dozzina di volte nella *Commedia*) solo nella prima forma.

Comment: +1 Per aggiungere un dato numerico, secondo lo Zingarelli “le reni” è in uso dal 1268, mentre il rene come organo da un momento imprecisato prima del 1698. L'_Enciclopedia Dantesca_ conferma che in Dante compare (una mezza dozzina di volte nella _Commedia_) solo nella prima forma.

Comment: @DaG: Nell'articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca si spiega che il lemma maschile singolare "rene" appare per la prima volta nel *Vocabolario degli Accademici della Crusca* nella terza edizione del 1691. Ma poi: «Nella quarta edizione (1729-1738) la situazione viene riesaminata e scompare il lemma *reni*, inglobato sotto *rene* con la glossa "Nel numero del più si trova usato tanto nel genere maschile, quanto nel femminile"».

Comment: Penso che la spiegazione del perché la "e" è chiusa o aperta in questi vocaboli si possa completare con le informazioni che si trovano sul libro *Italiano* di Luca Serianni nelle sezioni I.22, I.23 e I.25. @DaG: cosa ne pensi?

Comment: Perché, se ho capito bene, ambedue i termini provengono dallo stesso vocabolo latino: *rēn* *rēnis*.

Comment: Mi sembra giustissimo, Charo! Pare effettivamente un caso di doppia derivazione, popolare e dotta, con le rispettive diverse evoluzioni fonologiche.

Comment: Bene, forse cercherò di scrivere questa informazione più tardi.

Answer (score 3):

Questa non è una risposta completa. Si tratta unicamente di alcune spiegazioni che ho trovato nel capitolo I del libro *Italiano* di Luca Serianni e che intendono completare l'eccellente post di @Gio.

Come si vede nella risposta di @Gio, ambedue i termini, "le réni" e "il rène", provengono dallo stesso vocabolo latino, *rēn* *rēnis*, ma il momento e il modo in cui sono entrati a far parte del vocabolario italiano è completamente diverso. Il sostantivo femminile plurale "réni" si è formato a partire di un'evoluzione diciamo così "naturale" dal latino al volgare ed era già in uso nel medioevo. Invece il sostantivo maschile "rène" proviene dalla introduzione fatta alla fine del Seicento di un vocabolo latineggiante (dal latino *rēn*) come termine medico dotto per designare l'organo che produce l'orina.

Nella sezione I.22 del suo libro Serianni afferma:

> In latino le vocali si distinguevano in base alla quantità, ossia alla durata della loro articolazione, che poteva essere breve (VĔNIT 'viene') o lunga (VĒNIT 'venne'). Il sistema quantitativo entrò in crisi in età imperiale, quando le vocali brevi tendevano a essere pronunciate come aperte (quindi VĔNIT approssimativamente /'wεnit/) e le lunghe come chiuse (VĒNIT /'we:nit/). 
>   Il nuovo sistema oppositivo basato sulla qualità  (o timbro) ebbe presto ragione del vecchio, indebolitosi anche quando il latino, estendendosi in Europa e Africa, «si sovrappose a lingue che nel loro sistema vocalico non conoscevano l'opposizione fonematica fra vocali lunghe e vocali brevi» (TAGLIAVINI 1969: 237).

Nella sezione I.23, tra altre cose, si spiega come dalle vocali latine "ĕ" ed "ē" in sillaba tonica si ebbero in italiano (e nella maggior parte dell'area romanza) i resultati seguenti:

> - Ĕ --> /ε/
> - Ē --> /e/

Usando gli esempi della citazione precedente, questo spiega la ragione per cui si pronuncia "viène" con la "e" tonica aperta e invece "vénne" con la "e" tonica chiusa. In questo modo si può anche capire perché dal latino *rēn* si è derivato il vocabolo "réni" pronunciato con la "e" chiusa.

Tuttavia, nella sezione I.25 Serianni avverte:

> Gli esiti indicati sono propri delle *voci popolari*, ossia di quelle che sono state ininterrottamente in uso dalla latinità alla nascita del volgare (esaurendosi nell'italiano antico come *ghieva*<GLĒBAM 'zolla', o arrivando sino ad oggi, come tutti gli altri esempi citati). Nelle *parole dotte* (o *cultismi*), attinte dai libri in età medievale, rinascimentale o moderna, il vocabolo latino è stato adattato solo morfologicamente, mediante desinenza italiana, e si è mantenuta la vocale latina, quale che fosse la quantità (da notare che la *e* e la *o* – secondando la pronuncia del latino abituale ancora oggi – sono adattate come aperte, tranne che non risentano dell'analogia di altre forme): quindi [...]  CRUDĒLEM-*crudele* (pronunciato /kru'dεle/, non /kru'dele/, come ci aspetteremmo in caso di esito popolare).

Questo spiega perché, come accade nell'esempio sopra citato, anche il termine "rène", introdotto nella lingua italiana come un cultismo, ha la pronuncia della "e" tonica aperta e non chiusa.