# Come mai certi verbi cambiano di una o qualche lettera in base al contesto in cui vengono inseriti?

Tags: word-choice, etymology, single-words

Buongiorno a tutti. Sono interessato a capire come mai certi verbi mutano una o qualche lettera al loro interno in base al contesto in cui vengono inseriti.

---

**Esempio:**

- [arrossato](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/arrossare) si usa per esprimere, per dirne una: *quando l'occhio è divenuto rosso a seguito di un'infiammazione*;
- [arrossire](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/arrossire) si usa, invece, per esprimere: *quando il viso tende ad acquisire un colore tendente al rosso a causa di stati d'animo (come vergogna e rabbia)*.

**Nota:** Sono al corrente che non solo queste parole variano di poco tra loro per esprimere lo stesso concetto, che in sostanza è: *diventare rosso* (o avvicinarcisi). Ho solo fornito un esempio concreto.

**Domanda:** Come mai sono state inventate due parole che differiscono di poco per indicare la medesima azione anziché usarne una sola? (E come mai ci sono altre parole "duplicate" riconducibili a questo esempio?)

---

L'unico motivo che mi viene in mente è quello di riuscire a distinguere in modo maggiore, seppur sottile, certi elementi e/o periodi.

Comment: In realtà si tratta di due verbi: "arrossare" e "arrossire".

Comment: Hai ragione, mi sono confuso per il participio passato che è riconducibile all'aggettivo, ora ho corretto

Comment: Giusto per capire la tua domanda: i verbi "angustiare" e "angosciare" oppure "radiare" e "raggiare" sarebbero un esempio del fenomeno a cui ti riferisci?

Comment: Se è così, immagino che frequentemente c'entri il fenomeno degli "allotropi" (nell'articolo di Trifone citato in questa [risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/12793) ne trovi una spiegazione e parecchi esempi; un altro esempio di coppia di allotropi sono "i rèni" e "le réni" di cui si parla in questa [domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/9793) e le sue risposte), ma non sono sicura che sempre si tratti di allotropi.

Comment: Probabilmente, non ne sono sicuro, apprezzo molto l'intervento, anche se ora sono diventato più confuso. In questa domanda, mi sto riferendo a dettagli minimi, in cui i verbi richiamano la stessa cosa, ma differiscono di poco e uno si usa in un contesto più specifico, mentre l'altro in contesto più generico

Comment: Secondo la mia opinione, dovreste fare lo sforzo di definire in modo più chiaro cosa stai chiedendo nella domanda (magari facendo altri esempi). Altrimenti diventa molto difficile cercare di dare una risposta.

Comment: Ho cercato di individuare ulteriori esempi inerenti, ma non me ne sono venuti, qualora ci saranno novità, lo scriverò

Comment: Per "arrossare" e "arrossire": https://books.google.es/books?id=drmMDgAAQBAJ&pg=PT243&lpg=PT243&dq=arrossare+arrossire+allotropi&source=bl&ots=KOOFabWSI1&sig=ACfU3U2n-ncK-oqjL2m7-DBGfq9PkhmGRQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0xbj3oMHrAhWIEBQKHZzUBjoQ6AEwBXoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=arrossare%20arrossire%20allotropi&f=false

Comment: Grazie @Charo, ora mi sono tolto ogni dubbio e sono quindi sicuro che queste parole siano veramente degli allotropi, dunque si può arrivare alla conclusione che le supposizioni svolte nel corpo della domanda sono corrette

Answer (score -2):

A me sembra che sia una estensione a un verbo del fenomeno del plurale doppio, come spiegato in http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/plurali-doppi_(La-grammatica-italiana)/

Arrossi - in senso proprio
Arrossa - in senso figurato

Comment: Benvenuta/o su Italian.SE! Grazie del tuo intervento, ma non riesco proprio a capire il tuo ragionamento: se stiamo parlando di due verbi, cosa c'entra il plurale doppio di alcuni nomi?

Comment: Grazie per il riscontro, ma da quanto ho potuto verificare nel link allegato, si parla di nomi, non di aggettivi o di verbi, pertanto non credo che questo sia uno di quei casi

Comment: Forse vuoi dire che il fenomeno etimologico che c'è dietro è simile? Può darsi che sia così, ma dovresti aggiungere più dettagli.